# Joining three tables with comparing nullable columns

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench, inner-join

I have 3 tables:
Table 1 : COL1(Primary), COL2
Table 2 : COL1 (Primary, Nullable), COL2
Table 3 : COL1 (Primary), COL2 (Foreign key reference Table 1), COL3 (Foreign key reference Table 2), COL4

Now I want to join all the 3 tables and retrieve all the values of the table.
I have the following join query to fetch the data

```
select Table1.COL1,
Table1.COL2,
Table2.COL1,
Table2.COL2,
Table3.COL1,
Table3.COL4
from Table1
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.COL1=Table3.COL2
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.COL3=Table2.COL1;
```

As Table2.COL1 is nullable, no values are getting retrieved it is NULL.
How can I manipulate my query so that I retrieve all the columns even if Table2.COL1 is NULL with all the values in that column as NULL?

Comment: *COL1 (Primary, Nullable)* MySQL does not allow to use nullable column as primary key (the error message `All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead` is generated).

Comment: Will MySQL allow COL1 to be only UNIQUE(as it is foreign key in Table 3)

Comment: UNIQUE index have no restrictions for fields nullability. But when any part of index key is NULL then the whole record is not checked for uniqueness at all.

Comment: *How can I manipulate my query so that I retrieve all the columns even if Table2.COL1 is NULL with all the values in that column as NULL?* `FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table3 [LEFT | INNER] JOIN table1`.

Comment: So for _Table3: COL3 (Foreign key reference Table 2)_ will it also be NULL when _Table 2 : COL1 (Primary, Nullable)_ is NULL?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes it will be.

Comment: @tcadidot0 for example now I have 1 record in Table 1, 0 records in Table 2, and 250 records in Table 3 with COL3 as NULL, Now I want to retrieve the values. Is it possible? Or do I have to redesign the table structures?

Comment: @Subham , I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60483773/edit) and give us some of your example data that represents your situation so that we're able to do a testing and give suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN is meant for null handling while joining the tables. You may try below query -

```
select Table1.COL1,
       Table1.COL2,
       Table2.COL1,
       Table2.COL2,
       Table3.COL1,
       Table3.COL4
from Table2
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.COL3=Table2.COL1
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.COL1=Table3.COL2;
```

Comment: I am getting the same result. No records are being populated.